# A way of detecting incognito browsing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a way to detect if the user is browsing using "incognito mode"? No matter if it is PHP, JS, HTML or etc method.

Thanks!

Comment: can  you define what "incognito mode" is?

Comment: Private browsing. Ctrl (Command) + Shift + N in Chrome.

Comment: You may only find indirect indicators, for example if no advertisement cookies are present at all, but that is quite an effort, since you have to get around all the security measurements taken in today's browsers...

Comment: @MattS I've checked it, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @arkascha so there is no "easy way"? I can't believe.

Comment: @MattS 's link above lists a few approaches that sound logical. Give it a try.

Comment: so you dont want to detect other browsers 'privacy modes" just chrome?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It isn't surprising, though, I don't see how this is either useful for you or good for the user. You may be able to get some hints based on cookies and history, but I don't think you could distinguish a private tab from a just cleaned browser.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript window.RequestFileSystem function exists, but returns an error in incognito mode. Which is can be used to check incoginto mode.

Comment: Just tried this out in Chrome and I didn't see any error whilst trying to call `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` in Incognito mode.